# Scala objects constructed inside if

Tags: scala, instantiation

I want to do something I feel is simple, but I cannot figure out the way to do it. It is the following: according to some String variable I want to create an object of some specific type. However, the underlying objects have the same methods, so I want to be able to use this object outside the if block where the object is created. What is the best possible way to achieve it?

To ilustrate my need, here is the code:

```
var model = null
if (modelName == "KMeans") {
  model = new KMeans()
} else if (modelName == "BisectKMeans") {
  model = new BisectingKMeans()
}
model.setK(k)
model.fit(data)
```

Both `KMeans` and `BisectingKMeans` have the `setK` and `fit` methods. I want to create the object inside the if block but use the object outside it. This code gives an error when declaring the variable, as I'm not initializing it.

I've tried generic objects with a case class and declaring the variable as `Any` type, but cannot manage to get this to work, what is the best way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: Do you control those objects or are they provided by some third party library?

Comment: They are provided by a library, Spark MLLib. More precisely, they are these classes: [KMeans](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans) and [BisectingKMeans](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.BisectingKMeans)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala actually *does* allow you to do this with [structural types](https://www.baeldung.com/scala/structural-types):

```
type Model = { 
  def setK(k: Int): Any
  // the links in the question don't have a fit method
  def fit(???): ???
}

val model: Model = if (modelName == "KMeans") { new KMeans() } else { model = new BisectingKMeans() }
model.setK(k)
model.fit(data)
```

But it isn't particularly recommended to use if you have better alternatives due to use of reflection. I would simply call `setK` and `fit` inside the blocks in this specific case; or if not, create your own wrappers of `KMeans` and `BisectingKMeans` which implement a common trait.

Answer (score 3):

create your own interface and adapt the implementation to that. This will also work if you need to unify very different classes (different method names for example) into a common interface. Using `implicit def` is not required but does save the wrapping part at the call site

```scala
trait Model {
    def setK(): ??? // fill in your type
    def fit(): ??? // fill in your type
}

object Model {
    implicit def kmeansModel(kmean: Kmeans): Model = new Model {
        def setK() = kmeans.setK() // delegate to actual Kmeans
        def fit() = kmeans.fit() // delegate to actual Kmeans
    }
    
    implicit def bisectingKmeansModel(): Model = ??? // similarly

// usage
val model: Model = if (modelName == "KMeans") {
  new KMeans()
} else if (modelName == "BisectKMeans") {
  new BisectingKMeans()
} else {
  ??? // other cases
}

model.setK()
model.fit()
```

Comment: You probably should have `implicit def bisectingKmeansModel(kmean: BisectingKMeans): Model` similarly to `kmeansModel`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov thanks for catching! I was reaching for typeclass at the first iteration :)

Answer (score 2):

In order to invoke methods `.setK()` and `.fit()`, the compiler has to "know" that the variable `model` is of a specific type that has those methods. You're trying to say, "the variable *might* be this type or it *might* be that type but they both have these methods so it's okay."

The compiler doesn't see it that way. It says, "if it might be A and it might be B then it *must* be the LUB (least upper bound), i.e. the nearest type they both inherit from."

Here's one way to achieve what you're after.

```
class KMeans {  //parent type
  def setK(): Unit = ???
  def fit(): Unit = ???
}
class BisectingKMeans extends KMeans {
  override def setK(): Unit = ???
  override def fit(): Unit = ???
}

val model =
  if (modelName == "KMeans")
    new KMeans()
  else //always end with "else", never "else if"
    new BisectingKMeans()

model.setK()
model.fit()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The issue I'm getting after trying your response is that the LUB doesn't have the methods setK and fit, and thus it gives me a compilation error. Also I cannot change the classes, as they are coming from a library (see the comment in my original question).

Comment: If you can't change the classes then you can't try my suggested solution, so of course it doesn't work.